# PL/SQL Comparing Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have task of matching candidates in my database with suitable job vacancies based on skill and availability, using sql and pl/sql only.

I have managed to write the following code which matches available candidates to available vacancies.

```
 DECLARE
     CURSOR availableCandidates_cur IS
        SELECT * FROM candidate
        WHERE candidate.available = 'True';
     CURSOR availableJobs_cur IS
        SELECT *
        FROM position WHERE status = 'Open';
  BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Available Candidates with matching vacencies');
      FOR availableCandidates_rec IN availableCandidates_cur
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Candidate: ' || availableCandidates_rec.firstName || ' ' ||  availableCandidates_rec.lastName);
        FOR availableJobs_rec IN availableJobs_cur
        LOOP
          IF (availableCandidates_rec.positionType = availableJobs_rec.positionType) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(availableJobs_rec.positionName);
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END LOOP;
END;
```

I am struggling to figure out how to now match candidates to positions based on matching skills. The tables in question are

candidateSkills

```
candidateID | skillID
1           | 2
1           | 3
2           | 1
3           | 1
3           | 3
```

positionSkills

```
positionID | skillID
1           | 1
1           | 3
2           | 1
3           | 2
3           | 3
```

So for example i would like to output that

```
Candidate 1  Matches
position 3
Candidate 2 Matches
position 2
Candidate 3  Matches
position 2
position 3
```

I fear i may have gone down the wrong path intially which has lead to my confusion.

I would appreciate if someone could help steer me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected.  Candidate 3 matches jobs 1 and 2, candidate 2 matches job 2, candidate 1 matches job 3

```
select distinct c.cid, j.jid 
from candidate c, jobs j
where j.sid=c.sid
and not exists
(select 'x' from jobs j2 where j2.jid=j.jid
and j2.sid not in (select c2.sid from candidate c2
where c2.cid=c.cid))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

The query outputs each candidate.skill which matches any position.skilll

However, i need to check if a candidate fulfills every skill for a specific position in order to be a match, as displayed in the output in original post.

Comment: Thank you very much solved my problem perfectly. I managed to incoprate this code into my original pl/sql function to provide my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
--All candidates that match every skill in a position
select distinct candidateID, positionID
from
(
    --Match candidates and positions, count number of skills that match
    select candidateID, positionID, skills_per_position
        ,count(*) over (partition by candidateID, positionID) matched_skills
    from candidateSkills
    inner join
    (
        --Number of skills per position
        select positionID, skillID
            ,count(*) over (partition by positionID) skills_per_position
        from positionSkills
        where status = 'Open'
    ) positionSkills_with_count
        on candidateSkills.skillID = positionSkills_with_count.skillID
    where available = 'True'
)
where matched_skills = skills_per_position
order by candidateID, positionID;
```

Using these scripts to build the tables:

```
create table candidateSkills as
select 1 candidateid, 2 skillID, 'True' available from dual union all
select 1 candidateid, 3 skillID, 'True' available from dual union all
select 2 candidateid, 1 skillID, 'True' available from dual union all
select 3 candidateid, 1 skillID, 'True' available from dual union all
select 3 candidateid, 3 skillID, 'True' available from dual;

create table positionSkills as
select 1 positionID, 1 skillID, 'Open' status from dual union all
select 1 positionID, 3 skillID, 'Open' status from dual union all
select 2 positionID, 1 skillID, 'Open' status from dual union all
select 3 positionID, 2 skillID, 'Open' status from dual union all
select 3 positionID, 3 skillID, 'Open' status from dual;
```

However, my results are slightly different.  Candidate 3 matches position 1 and 2, not 2 and 3.  I hope this is just a typo in your example.

Also, I didn't format my output exactly like yours.  It can be a bit tricky to have SQL to display results in a multi-line format.  However, leaving the SQL unformatted will also make it more useful if you want to use it in some other process.